# Aggregating values based on condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below is a table using which I am trying to establish a table of content shown in table B.

Table A

| Sno. | Total | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 225 | 0 |
| 3 | 210 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0.5 |
| 6 | 150 | 0 |
| 7 | 150 | 0.5 |

Table B

| Total | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 435 | 3 |
| 300 | 1.0 |

I am trying to accumulate and get a result of **Total** and **Value** until both are defined (i.e. Row-3, Row 7) using SELECT statement. I have tried to use LEAD and LAG to check if both values are defined in table but its not working for me.

Comment: mysql and oracle are two different database products with different implementation of SQL.Which one do you use?

Comment: I am using Oracle / PLSQL

Comment: How do you distinguish partitions? Why you want first three and not first five together for example? What does "*until both are defined in a row*" mean?

Comment: Total should accumulate until both Total and Value column defined with non zero values, Similarly the same should happen for Values column as well. (Row 3 is defined with both Total and Value, but before this row you can see either any of the value is defined)

Comment: 10g version won't support MATCH_RECOGNIZE and I am using 10g version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   A
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY sno
  MEASURES
    SUM(total) AS total,
    SUM(value) AS value
  PATTERN (undefined* defined)
  DEFINE
    undefined AS total = 0 OR value = 0,
    defined   AS total > 0 AND value > 0
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE A (Sno, Total, Value) AS
SELECT 1,   0, 1   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 225, 0   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 210, 2   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   0, 0   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,   0, 0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 150, 0   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 150, 0.5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TOTAL | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 435 | 3 |
| 300 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IqTDPmE_)

---

In earlier versions, you can use analytic functions and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT SUM(total) AS total,
       SUM(value) AS value
FROM   (
  SELECT total,
         value,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN total = 0 AND value = 0 THEN 1 END)
           OVER (ORDER BY sno) AS grp
  FROM   A
)
GROUP BY grp;
```

Which outputs the same.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/feaadd/2)

Comment: I am using 10g version. But this is one of perfect solution

Comment: @Kumar Updated with a version that works on 11g and I think works on 10g (but I can't test it).